# How to exclude library from autocomplete in Netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete, intellisense

As I try to use the auto-complete pop-up window in Netbeans on my PHP project, a huge swath of CakePHP methods tend to fill the window, and it makes finding what I need more difficult. (I'm not even using CakePHP in the project...)

Is there a way to prevent CakePHP which I am not using, or generically any other library, from showing up in that window?

[image]

Thanks.

**Update:**

Disabling cakephp did remove it from the autocomplete window, but it looks like my primary issue is with the fact that netbeans didn't seem to know what object I am referring to in these cases (because it is a global/defined elsewhere)

When it knows the exact class it provides a proper list of methods to choose from. There seems to be a "red dot" graphic beside methods related to the object, and this "thought bubble" type graphic beside ones that are just grabbed from all libraries netbeans knows about

Comment: I think you should right click to the current project and open the properites. In the opened window select *frameworks* section and disable cakePHP if it'll be there.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a bit, I updated my question a bit for anyone's future reference.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have in my mind for this moment is to disable the **CakePHP** plugin. I have installed it separately so the path in my IDE is **Tools -> Plugins -> User Installed Plugins** (which is PHP CakePHP Framework).

[image: Disabling CakePHP]